# On Hover Button

Tags: css, onhover

I have a simple button, and I want to use CSS to make it onhover, bring up a dropdown of a few more buttons with links, and when the button is pressed I want the button to stay at the onhover state. How can this be accomplished? For example a games button that when hovered over it drops down to buttons that have different links to games. Sorry if this is unclear. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Do you want something like a mega menu? Checkout some examples here: http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/galleries/mega-menus/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not a plain CSS thing to do, but check out Drop, my lightweight script for this sort of thing. It's NOT jQuery - it's vanilla JavaScript.

http://cferdinandi.github.io/drop/

Answer (score 0):

I think this may take more effort than you're expecting. To make things much easier, I recommend using [Twitter-Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), which is a set of CSS/JS files that come packaged with usable components. The [Dropdown](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns) component is probably what you're looking for. It is built in with part of the functionality you desire, the other part can be done with jQuery.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="hoverbutton" class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Dropdown
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Here is the jQuery needed to make the hover effect:

```
$('#hoverbutton').mouseover(function() {
$('#hoverbutton').addClass("open");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

look into mouseover and mouseleave inside jquery.
you could come up with a simple function to detect if the mouse is over the element or not.

Since i have some source code open already here is some..

```
function over(ELEMENT){
            ELEMENT.mouseover(function(){
                //mouse over
            });
            ELEMENT.mouseleave(function(){
                //mouse not over
            });
        }
```